# Can Frobenius traces jump like crazy in non-geometric Galois representations?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If I have a continuous representation $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_l)$ ramified at finitely many places how can the Frobenius traces behave?

Assuming they lie in an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ can they grow exponentially with $p$? How much can $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ diverge?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

> "Assuming they're in an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ can they
> grow exponentially with ?"?

I'm not sure this statement will have a truth value, because I suspect the assumption never occurs: non-geometric $\ell$-adic representations are fundamentally $\ell$-adic analytic objects and I don't know of any mechanism which would force their Frobenius traces to be in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

[Here I'm assuming that your representations are irreducible; one can easily construct examples of extensions $0 \to \chi_1 \to V \to \chi_2 \to 0$ with $\chi_i$ geometric which are unram almost everywhere but non-geometric at $\ell$. But then the traces are the same as $\chi_1 \oplus \chi_2$ so the question is not interesting.]

There are examples of irreducible 2-dim'l non-geometric representations arising from non-classical overconvergent modular forms. I tabulated a bunch of these in [my first ever paper](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/doi/10.1093/imrn/rnm050/673208?redirectedFrom=fulltext) (paywall, arxiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701168)). The result is a list of $\ell$-adic numbers (computed modulo some high power of $\ell$), which are the q-expansion coefficients, or equivalently Frob traces at the first few primes; and they don't like they come from $\mathbb{Q}$ in any recognisable way.

Comment: If we drop the assumption about algebraicity can anything be said about the $l$-valuation of the traces?

Comment: All traces will be $\ell$-adically integral, and they'll behave like the trace of a random conjugacy class in $\operatorname{Im}(\rho)$, which is some irreducible subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n$. But that's not terribly deep and it's hard to say more than that.

Comment: When you say "random" can that be made more precise? Is there a conjecture like Sato-Tate for non-geometric representations?

Comment: Chebotarev density shows that the Frobenius conj classes are uniformly distributed in the l-adic topology -- this is far easier than Sato-Tate and geometricity is not required